# Protractor - Element not visible (but visible when checked manually)

Tags: css, protractor, element

I hope you could help me with this. I'm new to protractor. I cannot click an element in protractor, it says its not visible even if its visible when checked manually. Below are the details:

css code:

```
<div class="list" ng-click="openOtherUsers(perCrisis)" ng-show="detailView">
<div class="item item-input-inset content-bg search-bar">
<button class="button button-clear" type="button">
<i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
<label class="item-input-wrapper">
<i class="icon acc-search placeholder-icon"></i>
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="Search for people" ng-model="search.keywords">
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Protractor Code:

```
it("this is a trail for SEARCH click", function () {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    var search = element(by.css('.list.list'));
    //expect(search.isPresent()).toBeTruthy(); <<<<< PRESENT, but if     //isDisplayed is used: its false
    search.click(); 
});
```

FYI: parent class is list, i have also tried using "list"/ "[ng-click="openOtherUsers(perCrisis)"]"/"[ng-show="detailView"]" as css locator.

I hope you could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: any advances on this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the problem is that there could be an another element matching the locator. In this case you may need to improve your locator to uniquely identify the desired element.

Another thing that might help is a wait - we'll [wait for the element to become visible](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

```
var search = element(by.css('[ng-click="openOtherUsers(perCrisis)"]')),
    EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(search), 5000);

search.click();
```

Comment: hi @alecxe. Thanks for the reply, appreciate it. But it didn't worked, even extended the waiting time to 20secs, but still it didn't.

Comment: @MerBoyAnthonyDuran are you sure this element is the only one matching the locator - are you getting any warnings during the test run? Thanks

Comment: Hi @alecxe. I actually tried getting all elements, then clicking the first found element - but its still not working. I actually have a lot of elements that when click returns Element not visible error. I am new to protractor, so I really dont have an idea in dealing with it. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: When I tried getting all elements, i got an error: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

Comment: Hi again @alecxe. I guess you are right, there are many elements matching the locator - found it when I used isPresent (though isDisplayed returns false). How do you deal with this? I dont understand why it says it is not visible when during manual testing, it is visible.

Comment: @MerBoyAnthonyDuran thanks, can you share the link to the target site you are working with? As I've mentioned in the answer, you probably need to improve your locators to target the desired visible element.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant @alecxe. It is stored locally in my machine (from a repository). And it's actually a mobile app. Can you give me an example on how to improve the locators? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 'actions' to move the mouse to the element and then perform the click()

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(search, 1, 1).perform().then(function(){elem.click()});
```

Comment: Hi @CodeRJ. Thanks for the reply.Tried it, but it still returns Element not visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
isClickable: async function(el) {
  if (await el.isPresent()) {
    if (await el.isDisplayed()) {
      if (await el.isEnabled()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
},
```

I wrote this a while back to solve that problem. `await`'s require async(node 8+), but simplifies things. But that shows the hierarchy of accessibility for an element.

To be `enabled` it must be `displayed` and to be `displayed` it must be `present`